# Using select() on all existing columns AND using a list to generate new lit columns

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an existing df with n columns and I need to also add thousands of lit columns for a later application. Because there is so many columns to be added, I cannot use a for loop of withColumn().

Is it possible to combine the following two .select() functions?

```
df1 = df.select([lit(f"{i}").alias(f"{i}") for i in test_list])
df2 = df.select("*")
```

This didn't seem to work as well as a few other variations

`df1 = df.select("*", [lit(f"{i}").alias(f"{i}") for i in test_list])`

Comment: Try unpacking (*) the list with `select("*", *[lit(f"{i}").alias...)`.

Answer (score 0):

we can use `df.columns` which provides list of existing columns and append with `lit` columns.

```
df1 = df.select(df.columns+[lit(f"{i}").alias(f"{i}") for i in test_list])
```